# Upgrading 12.04 to 14.04 problem - system now unstable!

Tags: 12.04, 14.04

When I tried to upgrade 12.04 on my old 512 meg RAM machine to 14.04 it seemed to have trouble and now the system is unstable (screen title bar and application bar not appearing, etc.).  I have downloaded a DVD with the .iso file for 14.04 on it, but my machine does not want to boot from the DVD drive.  Machine is an HP 'Media Centre PC 873n' with 512 meg of memory.  Any idea how I can get it to boot from the DVD drive?  When I first installed Ubuntu it was a Windows PC and it didn't have any trouble booting the 12.04 Ubuntu from the DVD drive.

Comment: Have you tried an alternate DVD?  If the alternate fails, your DVD Drive may be bad...

Answer (score 1):

Sorry....  I think I answered my own question.  I double clicked on the .iso file and it did a self extraction and now the DVD seems to be installing on my Ubuntu computer.  Thank you.....  phil

Comment: @kraxor this is the OP's own answer :-)

Comment: Sorry guys, my bad! :)